# ruby query doesn´t get the symbol - or /

Tags: sql, ruby, activerecord-relation

I have the next line of code:

```
@selected_events = Evento.where(dia: "2014/11/20")
```

The question is that the result of the query shows me like if I did the query with just "2014", and its the same for "2014-11-20" and "2014 11 20". Its like its takes this symbols as an end of query or something.

```
> irb(main):007:0> Evento.where(dia: "2014/-/1120")
  Evento Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "eventos".* FROM "eventos"  WHERE "eventos"."dia" = 2014
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation ...>
```

Comment: What is the type of the dia attribute? It seems like it's an integer. "2014/11/20".to_i => 2014

Comment: Have you tried with '2014/11/20', so that ruby does not interpret symbols in the string?

Comment: You´re right Jiri, the problem was that the type on the migration was integer and i was trying to pass a String... 

Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like you want a `DATE` column but instead have an `INT`.